# It says my citations are undefined. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{a4,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {report/} }

\title{Can we use May's ideas to minimise risk in the financial system?}
\author{Thomas Castle}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
In 1972, Robert May made major advancements in population biology using mathematical techniques, determining that the stability of ecological networks decreases if the network is sufficiently large or complex after writing a paper in Nature (May, 1972) \cite{nat}. His work suggests that complex food webs within real ecosystems should not persist, although there exists many ecosystems with a large population of interacting species. Since then May's work has been extended to introduce various other variables including mutualistic relationships and nestedness which have been used to explain why such large systems may not just exist but also thrive. The applications of May's ideas are not just confined to population growth in ecosystems, his work has been used in the field of biodiversity and the study of diseases. More recently  May wrote an article in Nature regarding risks in the financial system and relating his work on the dynamics of ecological food webs with the complexity and stability in models of finiancial networks(May \& Haldane, 2011) \cite{ban2}. Even if our financial system reflects May's ideas on multi specie communities and is inherently unstable,the concepts behind his work may be able to minimise systematic risks in the ecosystem of our economy.

\section{A summary of May's ideas}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{nat} May, R.M. (1972). Will a Large Complex System be Stable?. \textit{Nature}. 238. pp.413--414.
\bibitem{ban} May, R.M \& Haldane, A.G. (2011). Systematic risk in the banking ecosystems. \textiy{Nature}. 469. pp.351--355.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `thebibliography` doesn't work with BibTex but is LaTeX-alone way of having a bibliography. Just leave BibTex out on compilation.

Comment: You cite `ban2`, but you have `ban` in your bibliography.

Comment: And of course, `\textiy` in the second bibliography entry should be `\textit`.

Comment: if you're using `amsart`, you don't need to specify either `amsmath` or `amsthm`.  (`amssymb` is still needed if you are using symbols from the ams fonts.)

Comment: TTC2483, please roll back your last edit. As you left it, you break the QA logic of the site. How to understand the answer below, if you deleted the original question? If you want to thank the answerer, you can add a comment to the answer itself.

Comment: I rolled back. Other ways of thanking is to vote up useful answers by clicking the up-arrow left of the post, and/or accepting an answer (which indicates the answer you found most helpful, and marks the question as solved)  by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- The document body features `\cite{ban2}`, but the citation key is `ban`. This has got to be harmonized.
- `\textiy` should be `\textit`, right?
- I would change "finiancial" to "financial". :-)
- Last but not least, it looks like you wish to create parenthesis-style authoryear-type citation call-outs with your hand-built `thebibliography` environment. If that's the case, I suggest you (a) load the `natbib` citation management package  and (b) provide an optional argument to each `\bibitem` entry, as is done in the example below. That way, you can use `\citep` to create parenthesis-style citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
%% I've streamlined the preamble to focus on the relevant parts
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} % just for this example

\begin{document}

\dots\ a paper in \emph{Nature} \citep{nat}. \dots

\dots\ in models of financial networks \citep{ban}. \dots

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[May(1972)]{nat} May, R.M. (1972). Will a Large Complex 
System be Stable? \textit{Nature}. 238. pp.~413--414.

\bibitem[May~\& Haldane(2011)]{ban} May, R.M. \& Haldane, A.G. 
(2011). Systematic risk in the banking ecosystems. \textit{Nature}. 
469. pp.~351--355.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, in the medium to long run you may want to learn how to use BibTeX, to let software handle the tedious process of creating the formatted bibliographies of your papers.